# Bad MYSQL design and how to improve it

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem tying to sort out a database which was when I started an unholy mix of Mysql, hand written back of envelope notes, Excel spreadsheet and completely missing records (don't ask) I have now reduced the problem down to the following.

I have 4 tables in greatly simplified form they are:-

```
customers
---------
id int not null primary key,
name varchar(50) 

users
---------
id2 int not null primary key,
name varchar(50)

address
-------
id int, 
id2 int, 
country varchar(50)

product
-------
id int, 
id2 int, 
item varchar(50)
```

Sample data:

Examples select * from customers;

```
+----+------+ 
| id | name | 
+----+------+ 
|  1 | Fred | 
+----+------+
```

select * from users;

```
+----+---------+ 
|id2 | name    | 
+----+---------+ 
|  1 | Wilma   | 
|  2 | Pebbles | 
+----+---------+
```

select * from address;

```
+----+-----+---------+ 
| id | id2 | country | 
+----+-----+---------+ 
|  1 |  1  | Bedrock | 
|  1 |  2  | Bedrock | 
+----+-----+---------+
```

select * from product;

```
+----+-----+---------+ 
| id | id2 | item    | 
+----+-----+---------+ 
|  1 |  1  | Item1   | 
|  1 |  2  | Item2   | 
+----+-----+---------+
```

customers.id is a primary key and links to address.id and product.id

users.id2 is a primary key and links to address.id2 and product.id2

This arrangement fails where more than one user shares an address with a customer the only way to work around this at present is to duplicate the record in address and change the id2 number. At present this only effects one case in the database.

Where users don't share an address with a customer I am unable to workout a select statement that will find Customers name, Customers address, Users name and Users address.
This situation applies to approximately 30% of the records.

Any suggestions on how to sort this chaos would be most welcome.

Richard

Comment: It's possible that you may have simplified out some important information. One of the things you said was: "This arrangement fails where more than one user shares an address with a customer". If id2 is the primary key on users, and the only way to link users to address is via id2, then how can more than one user share the same address? I also don't understand what the relationship is between products and the other tables - is there a missing orders table? Also, can you confirm whether this is an academic exercise / homework, or whether this is a commercial system?

Comment: Let this be a lesson to all of us to never name something `id2`.

Comment: This is sorting out records for an old friend of mine who has routinely run his business on hand written and in my experience mostly lost records. It is for a business but it certainly won't pay anything.

Comment: The reason I asked the last question is that there are frequently simplifications in academic exercises that are reasonable for conceptual purposes, but which would produce serious problems in real-life systems. Also, do you mind me asking whether you are familiar with normalization, or are you new to relational databases?

Comment: I am relatively new to relational databases but am aware of normalizaton and know that this is not fully normalized. I am just attempting to sort out and normalize the mess I have been given.

Comment: There is no missing orders table. There is no way to have duplicate id2 numbers in the users table or the address table but it is possible to have duplicate id numbers in the address table and this is what happens when you have 2 or more users sharing an address with 1 customer.

Comment: Do you mean that the same address is being represented by multiple records on the address table?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what I think you're describing: An address can be shared by multiple users, but a user/customer can only have one address.

It sounds like you have your many-to-one relationship backwards.

Meaning, you have a foreign key in the address table pointing to customer/user, when what you really want is a foreign key in the customer/user table pointing to address. But that's kind of ugly... so a couple of ways you might clean it up:

Is a customer also a user? If so, have a single foreign key in Address that points to User, and a foreign key from User to Customer would be fairly clean.

If not, you might consider a table that bridges User/Customer and address. Something like this:

```
User_Cust_ID,    Type,       Address_ID
1                Customer    5
2                Customer    1
1                User        1
```

That will allow you to resolve a user and customer that share the same address.

HTH...

Comment: It is worse than that some customers have up to 5 addresses in 3 different countries. For that matter I also have a user with 3 address.

Comment: Well, with the bridge table approach that's OK - you are resolving a many-to-many. A customer can have multiple addresses, and an address can belong to multiple customers.